# In what order will these functions get executed?

Tags: javascript, function

I am rewriting a project of mine and this time I decided to use self invoking functions to save a bit of code, but I became very uncertain if this would even work since I don't want the self invoking functions to be run before page has loaded + the `init` function has been run.

The expected execution order I want is this:

```
init: function() {
    //some code gets executed here
    createCalendar(2015);
}

addEventListnrs: (function() {
    //event listeners gets added here on elements that gets created
    //in the createCalendar function
})()

createCalendar: function(year) {
    //creates elements that the addEventListnrs uses
}

window.onload = init;
```

Question is, is this what I'm going to get or will the addEventListnrs function invoke itself before init gets run?

Comment: They won't get executed at all because there are syntax errors in the JS.

Comment: Your IIFE should be laid out like this: `(function(){}())` not `(function(){})()`

Comment: It's easy to test this. Have each function alert something, and see which one comes up first etc.

Comment: @minseong: Doesn't matter.

Comment: I am confused by your colons. Surely you are laying everything out like the properties of an object? Where's the object?

Comment: @minseong I looked at w3schools version of the self invoking function and they have it the way I've written it so I'm guessing that it works since their example works?

Comment: @minseong I've skipped a lot of code since it wasn't adding to the question.

Comment: Oh no, that way works, but it isn't recommended.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz you shouldn't rely on w3schools for best practice examples.

Comment: @minseong: Like I said, it doesn't matter. There's no rational recommendation to make either way, because they'll have the same outcome.

Comment: @minseong Oh? And what's the reason for that?

Comment: @PaulS. I never stated that it was best practice, only that I went with what they had written. minseong didn't state in the first comment that it should be the other way because of best practice.

Comment: @sixfingeredman The rational explanation is that you can go from an open parenthesis to it's close parenthesis and you have something meaningful between them. The invocation isn't "dangling on the end". It also has a tiny difference to do with _interpreted > invoked > returned_ vs _interpreted > returned > invoked > returned_ which isn't worth worrying about.

Comment: @PaulS.: We can have two different yet both entirely valid and rational opinions on what is considered "meaningful". As such, there isn't any objective reason to suggest one over the other. Not saying you, but it seems that most people who make such recommendations are just parroting Crockford.

Comment: @sixfingeredman - possibly the reason people insist it must be one way rather than the other is precisely *because* there is no reason to choose! i.e. Sayre's law: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sayre%27s_law

Comment: @DanielEarwicker: Interesting. I'd say it's either that, or they're just really enamoured with Crockford's ["dog balls"](http://youtu.be/eGArABpLy0k?t=1m10s). :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your labels are valid code (i.e. you've left some code out)

1. The *IIFE* labelled *addEventListnrs* invokes itself as soon as the interpreter reaches it
2. *...some time passes as the page loads... ...and it finishes loading*
3. The *load* event is sent to window
4. `init` is invoked by the listener
5. `createCalendar` is invoked by `init`

Comment: Your order is correct, but the way you've put it is a bit weird; IIFE is instantly invoked (as soon as the js loads), then, when the DOM is ready, init gets run, which triggers everything else.